# AutoLayout constraint issues in iOS 10, XCode 8

Tags: app-store, xcode8, ios10, ios-autolayout, xcode7.3

As I have developed the iOS application using `Xcode 7.3`. 
When reviewing the `AutoLayout` constraint on the device which having `iOS 10` using `Xcode 7.3` it properly display it but when using the `Xcode 8` and then reviewing on the device then it does not show properly.

So my question if I am deploy the application on the `AppStore` using `Xcode 7.3`, so there is any chance that the `AutoLayout` constraint do not show properly in `iOS 10`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issues in one of my iOS application as the constraint works in Xcode 7.x but not in Xcode 8, so I have found some work around for resolve it. Please find the below steps.

1) Open your `storyboard` in `Xcode 8`, then it popup regarding choose an initial device view, please select one of the option and then click on Choose Device. Please find the below GIF representation for same.

[image: GIF]

2) When you complete your changes, select the storyboard, go to File Inspector, on Interface Builder Document section, select the Opens In field and apply the `Xcode 7.x`. After that it popup regarding save so please select "Save and Close" option when it is prompted. Please find the below GIF representation for same.

[image: GIF]

3) Close the Xcode and then open the application.

*Your storyboard changes will be saved, and your storyboard will function as it did on Xcode 7.x.*

Hope it works for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The build given by Xcode 7.3 will not affect for constraint issue on iOS10.

Comment: Are you sure ? If there is any official link by Apple where it stated that.

Comment: But how would you sure about.