# xib files in Xcode 8.2 is not working properly.Is it a bug?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8.2

I am really frustrated since i migrated my project from Xcode 7.3 to Xcode 8.2. I am using both storyboard and Xib files in my project . While running my project I am getting this weird error. Some of my xib files are resized or reshaped(shrinked To fit/Expanded To fit). All this Xib files worked 100% perfectly in Xcode 7.3.

ScreenShot:
[image: screenShot]

As you can see above the above view controller xib is as on Iphone5. But while running it expands to the blue lines. I am perfectly sure the auto layout is correct. I have solved this by changing the opening type of the xib document from Xcode8 to Xcode7,but to no good effect. It seems repeating again and again. In the above layout my views are arranged like this. Why is this happening. Is it a bug

Already tried:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497572/layout-issues-after-updating-to-xcode-8)

ScreenShot:
[image]

Comment: are u working with swift or objective c

Comment: Swift 2.3... i think it doesn't really matter about the programming language

Comment: Have you tried changing Size Class in Interface Builder?? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

Comment: Yes I did.. I tried changing trait variant of xib files.

Comment: Please review the link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628249/autolayout-constraint-issues-in-ios-10-xcode-8/40735930#40735930) which might help you.

Comment: It initially changes, but on Opening xcode  again it is present again

Comment: Its been like this since I updated to Xcode 8.2 . I cannot update to Xcode 8.3 as it has no support for swift 2.3.

Comment: did you try changing constraints relative ? it seems your constraints are relative to margined of the layout guide, you can edit the constraints, or re add with unchecking relative to margin check button while adding constraints.

Comment: ok I tried.. but when i checked the constraints to margin was already unticked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Xcode. Your best option would be to update to Xcode 8.3 and migrate your Swift 2.3 code to 3.1.

Comment: is there a way of solving it?

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 8, it's highly recommended to use Size classes with universal layout developed using AutoLayout constraints. This helps in designing the user interface to support all iOS device family variants and also supports all device orientations. XIB files should be used as references and using the same UI controls on storyboard UI views.

Comment: I tried using size class for xib .. But the same prevail.